# Can VS Code run on Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

Does anybody know about plans of MS to support running VS Code so it can run on Android OS?

Comment: well I gave up, I end up using the very interface of GitHub ....  on my tablet that uses Android .... it's actually not that had ...

Comment: Can the question be reopened, now that Daniel has edited it to be clear? Or does it somehow still lack "focus"? (That seemed to relate to the original question, which could be read to imply the question was about developing Android apps, rather than simply running vs code ON Android, to edit any files it  may support).

Comment: I am running vs code on android as follows: installed termux, vnc-viewer -> ubuntu-chroot on termux -> https://github.com/futurejones/code-oss-aarch64

Comment: used https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Ubuntu +GUI. the result: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LKsDZYrMA1maUY1X9

Comment: Now you can use VS Code on Android, just Install Chrome Browser, go to `chrome://flags` and turn on **Accessibility Page Zoom**. Now just visit vscode.dev and turn on "Desktop Site" option in browser menu and you are done :)

Comment: @0xB00B you can also install it as a PWA in the Edge browser on Android.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Running the Electron-based VS Code on Android is not possible, at least until Android support is implemented in [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). This has been rejected by the Electron team in the past, see [electron#562](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/562)

[GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces) enables running VS Code in a browser with a backend container. https://vscode.dev and https://github.dev are VS Code without a backend that can connect to things like your local machine or a GitHub repository.

It's also possible to run VS Code on Android by installing Linux on your Android device as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613238/1156119).

Comment: This is no longer the case, see Bryan's answer

Comment: @Felipe I believe that's a different thing though. I take the OP to mean "Can I run VS Code on Android" (no due to Electron), not "Does VS Code support Android development" (there may be an extension for thank).

Comment: @Felipe why downvoting an answer which said the truth when is was written?The answer you are referencing has been posted more than a year later than this one

Comment: @Apperside voting guidelines are somewhat blurry, but revolve around "Is this answer useful".  Since this deals with information (regarding vscode support) and not library compatibility of someone's code, it is misleading and should not be at the top, since someone who Googles the question may come here and be lead to believe that vscode has not changed since 2016. At minimum it should no longer be the accepted answer

Comment: Seeing @DanielImms comment though, I think he's right. I am removing the vote

Comment: @Felipe to be clear, the answer is still correct and valid; Android support is not going to happen. Source: I'm part of the Electron maintainers group. The question states "MS to support VS Code on the Android platform", not "Android support in VS Code".

Comment: VSCODE Being tied to electron makes no sense, some of it's components already run on the web.

Comment: Just re-read the question about running VS Code on Android, this answer is correct in reading the question accurately.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adelphes.android-dev-ext

Comment: Now you can run VS Code on Android, check out https://github.com/vhqtvn/VHSCode-Android

Note: Document is on the way. PRs are welcome.

Comment: go http://github.dev and u get nice VS Code on any web enabled device

Answer (score 27):

I don't agree with the accepted answer that the lack of electron prevents VSC on Android.

Electron is really the desktop equivelent of projects like Apache Cordova or Adobe PhoneGap (but Electron is much less efficient and will presumably give way to solutions much closer to Cordova/PhoneGap when possible - it is already being worked [on eg. here](https://github.com/pojala/electrino).)

API's would need to be mapped from their electron equivelents, and many of the plug-ins will have their own issues (but Android is reasonably flexible about allowing stuff like Python compared to iOS) so it is doable.

On the other hand, the demand for an Android version of VSC probably comes from people using the new Chromebooks that support Android, and there is already a solution for ChromeOS using crouton, [available here](https://code.headmelted.com/).

Comment: People like me with Samsung DeX also want Visual Studio Code. It's not just ChromeOS users.

Comment: Minor addendum: Apache Cordova _is_ Adobe PhoneGap

Comment: @shaunRoselt please see updated answer

Answer (score 10):

There is a browser-based application that allows you to develop on a browser on your Android or any other device in a VSC-like environment. Check it out here:

https://stackblitz.com/

**Edit:** This is not the exact VSC implementation and it does not have all the features of VSC, such as extensions. It's just a VSC-like environment.

Comment: Now THAT'S cool. Do you know if anything of the sort is available for C/C++?

Comment: Wow, that actually works.

Comment: This is very misleading. What stackblitz does is reusing VSCode's UI elements and the monaco-editor (based on the editor used in VSCode). It is NOT an implementation of VSCode itself, because you cannot install extensions, toggle all those settings etc. It is more like a modern, file-based version of jsfiddle/jsbin.

Answer (score 7):

To date, there isn't a native VS Code editor for android, but projects do exist like [Microsoft/monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) which aim to provide a native experience in the browser.

[CodeSandbox](http://codesandbox.io) is a sophisticated online editor built around Monaco

Comment: Great project! But for what reason we have to have fork from the VS Code?

Comment: @EmbeddedDev I'm not exactly sure what your trying to ask, but the Monaco editor is based from the same source code as VSCode hence its forked

Comment: The difference is that VSCode allows you to run command-line tools while Monaco is "just" a text editor.  Running in-browser, you're never going to get command-line support without something like SSH under the hood.

Comment: Monaco is a text editor. VSCode allows plugin installation, cli execution and debugging extensions. the problem is that regarding to their website it isn't supported on mobile platforms.

Comment: Monaco by default does not support mobile. It may technically function if you try it out but certain things about the touch keyboard and the touch screen for the input sometimes won't work

Answer (score 6):

*The accepted answer is correct as asked, below answers the opposite question of developing Android on VS Code.*

Extensions

- Android : https://github.com/adelphes/android-dev-ext
- Emulator: https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/Emulator

Ultimately you can automate building and running your app on a device emulator by adding the function below to your `$PATH` and running `runDebugApp <module> <start activity>` from the integrated terminal:

```
# run android app
# usage runDebugApp [module] [fully qualified start activity com.package/com.package.MainActivity]
function runDebugApp(){
  ./gradlew -offline :"$1":installDebug && adb shell am start "$2" && adb logcat -d > logcat.log
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a 3rd party debugger in the works, it's currently in preview, but you can install the debugger Android extension in VSCode right now and get more information on it here:

https://github.com/adelphes/android-dev-ext

Comment: While useful, this is answering something that was *not* asked in the original actual question of running VS Code *on* Android.