# How to run VS Code on Android Device

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, arm

I have Galaxy tab S6 and it has cool features to replace laptop like connecting mouse and keyboard, but it unfortunately running Android OS, and not a lot of development apps are available to Android, so I thought if there's an option to run VS code at least on my device?

Comment: related with no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290113/can-vs-code-run-on-android

Comment: @Martin Zeitler please check other question has not valid answer

Comment: The other question is closed as well.

Comment: @MartinZeitler we got answer here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update: Simply go to [github.dev](https://github.dev) from your device and add to home screen.

> I Wrote this post using Linux Ubuntu on Galaxy Tab S6 ARM64 Based
> Processor using full version of chromium. and the following methods can be applied on any high-end android device ;)

**You have 2 ways to install Linux:**

- First *easy way* (Virtual Network Computing) (VNC):

**1. Install a Linux distro via "Termux"**

```
<code> pkg update -y && pkg install proot wget tar pulseaudio  -y &&  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndronixApp/AndronixOrigin/master/Rootfs/Ubuntu19/ubuntu19.sh && chmod +x ubuntu19.sh && ./ubuntu19.sh </code>
```

**2. Install Linux GUI desktop environment like "Xfce".**

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies -y
```

**3. start a VNC server on your linux.**

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver -y
```

**4. Open ["VNC Viewer"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android&hl=en) on android to start hacking.**

you may need to do command `vncserver -list` to list the port

**5. Install [vscode for arm64](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)**
**6. Optional: Install NodeJS for arm64**

````
```apt install nodejs```
````

- Second hacky way (Linux Natively):
- install bootable linux environment
- boot and install linux

more info:

https://medium.com/@quantvc/running-debian-on-android-device-natively-73545c9b0757

Helpful Resources:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android

Comment: this first option is tested and is working for me https://photos.app.goo.gl/LKsDZYrMA1maUY1X9

Comment: @shmuelfriedman great it worked for you too

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,

There are few IDE that can run on Andriod devices.

1. JavaIDEdroid
2. Java Editor
3. DroidEdit
4. Code Peeker Pro: Source Reader
5. Anacode IDE

[Android Apps and IDE](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/12/android-apps-ide-for-java-coder-programmers/)